# Passing options to cmake in bash script

Tags: bash, make, arguments, cmake

I am trying to write a script that will build multiple cppUtes lib.a files for different sanitizers with a bash script.

When trying to pass the compiler flags as variables to cmake I am unable to correctly format them. Please see the brief example below.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
set -euo pipefail
COMMON_OPTS='-fno-common -g -fno-omit-frame-pointer'
ASAN_OPT='-fsanitize=address'
ASAN_C_FLAGS="-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=\"$ASAN_OPT $COMMON_OPTS\""

echo "cmake ../ $ASAN_C_FLAGS"
cmake ../ $ASAN_C_FLAGS
make
```

The output of echo is what I expect, and what works for setting flags when not running in a bash script:

```
cmake ../ -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-fsanitize=address -fno-common -g -fno-omit-frame-pointer"
```

However, when I run the script cmake is not interpreting the flags correctly. They do not appear in the cmake flags that are displayed during the configuration:

```
CppUTest CFLAGS: -include "/home/ubuntu/cpputest/include/CppUTest/MemoryLeakDetectorMallocMacros.h" -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -Wswitch-default -Wswitch-enum -Wconversion -Wsign-conversion -Wno-padded -Wno-long-long -Wstrict-prototypes
```

and finally, I get the following compilation error from make:

```
c++: error: unrecognized argument to '-fsanitize=' option: 'address -g -fno-omit-frame-pointer'
```

Any help would be kindly appreciated.

Comment: I think it's related to the [difference between $* and $@](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3008695/3700414) ie your arguments are getting bunched up. How to unbunch... Not sure

Comment: Also see comment by [Carlo Wood](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17094086/3700414)

Comment: Thank you for you coments @Rusi I am not sure how to interpret the answers from those questions as I am not using any command line inputs. Tying to wrap the cmake argument in quotes eg: `cmake ../ "$ASAN_C_FLAGS"` gives the same results.

Comment: I'm away from a machine (on phone) and can't try hence only comments... Sorry! What I would try is to write a bash function as in @artswri answer, receive them as "$@" and ensure that the count is as you expect. In any case you can use that approach to verify counts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do consider using an array to hold the options.  That way, you would still be able to properly give them to `cmake` as separate argument, and not as a single string that the shell will split on whitespaces and perform filename globbing on.

The `sh` shell generally does not support arrays, so I have changed the `#!`-line to invoke `bash` instead:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

common_opts=( -fno-common -g -fno-omit-frame-pointer )
asan_opt='-fsanitize=address'
asan_c_cflags=( -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="$asan_opt" "${common_opts[@]}" )

echo "cmake ${asan_c_cflags[@]} ../"
cmake "${asan_c_cflags[@]}" ../
make
```

Here, the array allows us to pass multiple quoted arguments to `cmake` without demoting these to a single string and relying on the shell to split+glob it correctly.  This also allows us to properly pass argument potentially consisting of strings with spaces in them.

Related:

- [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444946/how-can-we-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable)

Comment: Thank you for your solution. This helped clean up the script and make it more readable. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that due to escaped quotes in your `ASAN_C_FLAGS`, CMake sees a quoted value for its `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` variable, and thus passes the entire thing as a single argument to your compiler. After removing those escaped quotes, CMake should correctly split the passed arguments at their whitespace before passing them to the compiler.

Comment: That is frustrating... removing the quotes entirely dose work. It dose not show that they have been appended in the cmake output but after building I can see they were appended. Thanks for your answer.